# Error on Python - Pandas, in the creation of a table

Tags: pandas, dictionary, indexing, datatable, keyerror

I want to create a table with a dictionary with brands and followers attributes. But I recive the error

```
KeyError: "[...] not in the index"
```

And I don't know how to fix it

## This is my code:

```
with open(bdir+'attribute_SPS_example.pkl', 'rb') as f:attributes_SPS= pickle.load(f)
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(attributes_SPS, orient='index').reset_index()
df = df.rename(columns={'index':'brand'})
df.index = df['brand']
```

```
df1 = df[brands]
display(df1.head())
```

Comment: Can you explain what the variable brands in `df[brands]` contains? Or did you got a typo there and meant df['brand']?